# How to convert string to date

Tags: php, date, datetime

I would convert a string like that "July 22, 2011 in 7:42pm" in a different format.
I tried to use both strtotime and date_parse_from_format functions but they don't correctly work in this case. I suppose that the reason of this problem could be the substring "in".

How can I convert that format in a Date type or in a timestamp?

Comment: just delete "in" from your string

Answer (score 3):

> I suppose that the reason of this problem could be the substring "in".

As far as I can see you are right. At least the `i` is an identifier ("Minutes with leading zeros") itself, thus you must escape it.

```
var_dump(date_parse_from_format('F d, Y \i\n g:ia', $string));
```

See [`date()` Example #2](http://php.net/function.date#example-637)

Answer (score 1):

Hey try the following solutions

```
print $date = "July 22, 2011 in 7:42pm";
$date = date_parse_from_format('F j, Y * h:iA', $date);
print '<pre>'; print_r($date);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would convert a string like that "July 22, 2011 in 7:42pm" in a different format.

The static method `DateTime::createFromFormat()` ([**documentation**](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)) (or alias `date_create_from_format()`) is preferred. Below is an example of its use for your needs, but be sure to absorb the information found in the documentation.

> How can I convert that format in a Date type or in a timestamp?

Below is a basic example. For the available formatting characters, see the [**`date()` manual page**](http://php.net/date).

```
$subject = 'July 22, 2011 in 7:42pm';
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('F d, Y \i\n g:ia', $subject);

// Output as another format (2011-07-22 19:42:00)
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Output as Unix timestamp (1311327720)
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```