# DateTime conversion to support mysql datetime datetype

Tags: mysql, php

How to convert this date-time "17 Apr, 2012 05:50 PM" in php to support mysql datetime format ie 2012-04-17 17:50:00 (seconds as 00 by default).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799435/how-to-convert-string-to-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
 $time = str_replace(',', '', "17 Apr, 2012 05:50 PM"); //remove comma
 $mysql_date =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time));
```

Comment: output is ----  1970-01-01 00:00:00 , I already dit this thing but still guessing what im missing

Comment: @swapnesh above code is showing me the right result as "2012-04-17 17:50:000.0000005000"

Comment: @heyanshukla yeah actually comma was not removed in earlier post :) ..and after comma removal the code is working fine

Comment: @safarov Good trick. But Its better to use `DateTime::createFromFormat` as in my answer.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im yes your answer is better. But make sure that OP using php version >= 5.3

Answer (score 3):

**Use standard [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class**,

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, Y H:i A', '17 Apr, 2012 05:50 PM');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Update:**
Just did some benchmark. It seems `DateTime::createFromFormat` method is **1.3x faster** thann `strtotime, str_replace` method.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the time using `strtotime` function